# Картинка заглушка

Tags: html, css, jquery

```css
hero__img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 560px;
    height: 660px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero__img" style="background-image: url('images/scooter_guy.png');"></div>
```

**Как вставить картинку заглушку?**

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите чтобы background-image заменялся другой картинкой, если одна не прогрузилась?

Comment: Да. Чтобы background-image заменялся другой картинкой. @T0xee.n17

Comment: Всё время думал, что контейнеры изображений имеют  background-image на случай отсутствия изображения, а само изображение грузится во внутреннем элементе. В чём необходимость менять именно фоновое изображение, а не грузить в отдельном элементе? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: В курсе поп рограмированию запрещено вставлять фоновіе картинки в тег <img>. И при єтом надо чтоб картинка біла вставлена инлайново чтоб е' могли заменить через админку

Comment: С background image конечно сложнее. В целом некоторые сервисы сами отправляют заглушки если указан неправильный адрес. Также можно сделать и в вашем проекте - если конечно есть доступ к бэку

Comment: Вотакой варинат пробавал но он рабоатет только для  <img>
`$('img').on('error', function () {

    $(this).attr('src', '../images/no-image.jpg');
    $(this).css({
      'border-radius': '0 0 0 0'
    });
  });`